# Passing model properties to query string within jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

```
 window.open("/Mail/Decrypt/?Agent=" + encryK, '_blank', 
'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
```

here, Mail is the controller name and Decrypt is the method name and takes in a string parameter which i'm passing the value.
Now if suppose i want the method takes in model properties,how to pass the same to the method in query string

Comment: What do you mean by model properties ?

Comment: public class UserModel
    {
        public string AgentID { get; set; };
        public string Key { get; set; } ;
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    } now this i want to pass in query string.how to do it?